# Syntax error in my sql query (ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my mysql query, I try to do the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but Ill get error, and I dont know why, maybe because I'm doing it wrong with my update statement. Here is my sql code:

```
$q3='INSERT INTO prestashop.ps_product_supplier (product_supplier_reference,product_supplier_url) values ("%s","%s") WHERE id_product=%d ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prestashop.ps_product_supplier SET product_supplier_reference= "%s", product_supplier_url= "%s" WHERE id_product = %d';

$sql3 = sprintf($q3, $_REQUEST['tki'],$_REQUEST['tki2'], $_REQUEST['id']);
```

I know its unsafe method to use $sql3 like that! But Im using it for my personal needs

Comment: $q3='INSERT INTO prestashop.ps_product_supplier (product_supplier_reference,product_supplier_url) values ("%s","%s")  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_product=%d ';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$q3='INSERT INTO prestashop.ps_product_supplier (id_product,product_supplier_reference,product_supplier_url) values (%d,"%s","%s") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prestashop.ps_product_supplier SET product_supplier_reference= "%s", product_supplier_url= "%s" WHERE id_product=%d';

$sql3 = sprintf($q3, $_REQUEST['tki'],$_REQUEST['tki2'], $_REQUEST['id']);
```

Comment: Im still getting an syntax error, this may occur because some product_supplier_reference/url are nulls but they have an id. And also replace gave me also a syntax error. This my database imgur.com/a/2Nhn8

Comment: run the query as it is from phpmyadmin for example and use some demo values, do you get error? @Somepub

Comment: I did, and I found out replace nor input is working, because I have a another sql column: id_supplier and the error is: "Field 'id_supplier' doesn't have a default value"  and I think I just need to replace the same id_supplier by id

Comment: And im little bit stupid, because I have other column and of course replace and insert aint working, but my question now is how can I replace/insert the values that I need and keep same values in other columns

Comment: @Somepub  use a simple `UPDATE` :) after all the row already exists and has a unique or primary key. Just update the fields you want.

Comment: @Somepub  in case it is a three column table as in the question then use the syntax in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q3='INSERT INTO prestashop.ps_product_supplier (product_supplier_reference,product_supplier_url) values ("%s","%s") WHERE id_product=%d ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prestashop.ps_product_supplier SET product_supplier_reference= "%s", product_supplier_url= "%s"';

$sql3 = sprintf($q3, $_REQUEST['tki'],$_REQUEST['tki2'], $_REQUEST['id'],$_REQUEST['tki'],$_REQUEST['tki2']);
```

Comment: Thank you for your all answers, but I still get an syntax error, this may occur because some product_supplier_reference/url are nulls but they have an id. And also replace gave me also a syntax error. This my database http://imgur.com/a/2Nhn8

Answer (score 0):

In your case it would be easier to use the REPLACE statement
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html

```
$q3='REPLACE INTO prestashop.ps_product_supplier (id_product,product_supplier_reference,product_supplier_url) values (%d,"%s","%s")';
$sql3 = sprintf($q3,$_REQUEST['id'], $_REQUEST['tki'],$_REQUEST['tki2']);
```

Also the error in your query is that you use the WHERE clause in INSERT statement 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

```
$q3='INSERT INTO prestashop.ps_product_supplier (id_product,product_supplier_reference,product_supplier_url) values (%d,"%s","%s") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_supplier_reference= "%s", product_supplier_url= "%s"';
$sql3 = sprintf($q3,$_REQUEST['id'], $_REQUEST['tki'],$_REQUEST['tki2'],$_REQUEST['tki'],$_REQUEST['tki2']);
```

Comment: Im still getting an syntax error, this may occur because some product_supplier_reference/url are nulls but they have an id. And also replace gave me also a syntax error. This my database imgur.com/a/2Nhn8

Comment: i had a syntax error in the replace statement, please try the edited one (removed the where clause) , also the INSERT INTO statement does not have a WHERE clause , it would be easier next time if you post your syntax errors.